# memory leak in imageview

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks

I'm getting memory leak problem in this code:

```
UIImage myImage1 = [[UIImage alloc]
    initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strimg1]]];
```

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can creating a variable of type UIImageView and then setting it to a UIImage.  The types don't match, are you sure the example is correct?

Comment: Ditto on Twelve47's comment. Björn Marschollek's response is incorrect, though you do need to release the image view at some point, obviously

Comment: And the "*" is also missing... this whole thing won't even compile!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that whenever you create an an Object using  New or Alloc init,
it is your responsibility to release it in the dealloc. and remember to used super dealloc.

Make sure no other object bump the retain count.

What is in the init method? Did you create another instance of class UIImage? Just a thought.

Hope this help.  dibu2z

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImage *myImage1 = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]]];
UIImageView *myimg=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage1];
[self.view addSubview:myimg];
[myimg release];
```

it may helps you.